# What is my error in calculating expected value of a negative binomial random variable?

Tags: probability, expectation, negative-binomial

We perform Bernoulli trials until $r$ failures ($P.(\text{fail}) = u$) occur. What is the probability that $k$ successes occur?
    \begin{align*}
    p(k) = {r + k - 1 \choose k} u^r (1 - u)^k
\end{align*}

What is the expected number of successes before $r$ failures occur?
    \begin{align*}
    &\quad \mathbb{E}(p(k)) \\
    &= \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} k p(k) \\
    &= \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} k {r + k - 1 \choose k} u^r (1 - u)^k \\
    &= \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} k \frac{(r + k - 1)!}{k! (r + k - 1 - k)!} u^r (1 - u)^k \\
    &= \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} k \frac{(r + k - 1)!}{k! (r - 1)!} u^r (1 - u)^k \\
    &\text{$0! = 1$, so when $k = 0$, the summand is $0$} \\
    &= \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} k \frac{(r + k - 1)!}{k! (r - 1)!} u^r (1 - u)^k \\
    &= \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(r + k - 1)!}{(k - 1)! (r - 1)!} u^r (1 - u)^k \\
    &= (1 - u)\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(r + k - 1)!}{(k - 1)! (r - 1)!} u^r (1 - u)^{(k - 1)} \\
    &\text{let $j = k - 1$} \\
    &= (1 - u) \sum_{j = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(r + j)!}{j! (r - 1)!} u^r (1 - u)^{j} \\
    &= r(1 - u) \sum_{j = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(r + j)!}{j! r!} u^r (1 - u)^{j} \\
    &= r(1 - u) \sum_{j = 0}^{\infty} {r + j \choose j} u^r (1 - u)^{j} \\
    &= r(1 - u) \lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j = 0}^{\alpha} {r + j \choose j} u^r (1 - u)^{j} \\
    &\text{let $r + j = \alpha$} \\
    &= r(1 - u) \lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j = 0}^{\alpha} {\alpha \choose j} u^{\alpha - j} (1 - u)^{\alpha - r} \\
    &= \frac{r(1 - u)}{(1 - u)^r} \lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j = 0}^{\alpha} {\alpha \choose j} u^{\alpha - j} (1 - u)^{\alpha} \\
    &= \frac{r}{(1 - u)^{r - 1}} \lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty} (u + 1 - u)^\alpha \\
    &= \frac{r}{(1 - u)^{r - 1}} \lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty} 1^{\alpha} \\
    &= \frac{r}{(1 - u)^{r - 1}} (1) \\
    &= \frac{r}{(1 - u)^{r - 1}}
\end{align*}

However, Wikipedia states that the expectation should be $(1 - u)r/u$. Where did I make an error in the above calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step that uses the binomial theorem by letting $r + j = \alpha$ is incorrect, because the statement of the binomial theorem cannot be used since $r + j$ depends on $j$. For more detail, see the answers to this question:[Proof for the calculation of mean in negative binomial distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672714/proof-for-the-calculation-of-mean-in-negative-binomial-distribution)