# Expectation of negative binomial distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, negative-binomial

Given $X \sim \text{NBin}(n,p)$, I've seen two different calculations for $\mathbb{E} (X)$:

\begin{align*}
&1. \mathbb{E} (X) = \frac{n}{p}, \quad \text{or}\\
&2. \mathbb{E} (Y) = \frac{n(1-p)}{p}
\end{align*}

Proof for 1.: [Proof for the calculation of mean in negative binomial distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672714/proof-for-the-calculation-of-mean-in-negative-binomial-distribution/1675392#1675392)

Proof for 2: Although I can't find a concrete proof on stackexchange, this is the expected value used in the wikipedia article for negative binomials, and I have also seen this value used in some questions here.

I've heard someone say that both are valid depending on the way you define the negative binomial, but I still don't quite understand the difference between the set-ups for the two different $\mathbb{E} (X)$.

Could someone explain their differences? Thank you!

Comment: You can find definitions of$NBin(r,p)$ here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The negative binomial distribution is the sum of $n$ i.i.d. geometric distributions.**

As for the [Geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution), alse for the NBinomial you have 2 kinds of parametrizations

1. The variable counting the total trials to get $n$ successes
2. The variable counting the total failures to get $n$ successes

**Thus you can prove your expectations in the following way:**

1. Start from the Geometric distribution that counts how many trials you need to get the first success:

$$P(X=x)=q^{x-1}p$$

$x=1,2,3,....$ and $q=1-p$

2. Calculate $\mathbb{E}[X]$

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=p\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}q^{x-1}=p\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{d}{q}q^x=p \frac{d}{dq}\frac{q}{1-q}=\dots=\frac{1}{p}$$

Hence the expectation of the NBinomial counting how many trials you need to get $k$ successes is simply

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
\mathbb{E}[\Sigma_i X_i]=k\frac{1}{p}
\qquad (1) 
}
$$

3. note that the geometric distribution counting the failures before the first success is

$$Y=X-1$$

Thus its mean is $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\frac{1}{p}-1=\frac{q}{p}$

Hence the Expectation of the NBinomial counting the number of failures before you get $k$ successes is

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
\mathbb{E}[\Sigma_i Y_i]=k\frac{q}{p}
\qquad (2) 
}
$$

...that's all!

Comment: Oh I see. So the first definition is the expected number of trials (successes + failures) before n (or k) successes, while the second is the expected number of *failures* before n (or k) successes?

Comment: @punypaw : Yes, absolutely correct